# Doubts for beginners in Python. How do I convert an array with hexadecimal values ​to bytes?

Tags: python, arrays, hex

```
# Recebe o número de 4 dígitos como input
number = input("Digite o número da Conta com 4 dígitos: ")

# Converte cada caracter em uma string e armazena em um array
number_array = list(number)

# Converte os valores '0' em '10' no array
for i in range(len(number_array)):
    if number_array[i] == '0':
        number_array[i] = '10'

# Converte os valores nesse array em hexadecimal
hex_array = [hex(int(num))[2:] for num in number_array]

# Adiciona um 0 antes de cada string dentro do array
final_array = ['0' + num for num in hex_array]

print(final_array)

bytes_sent = ('\x11\xb0\x12') + (final_array[0]) + (final_array[1]) + (final_array[2]) + (final_array[3]) + ('\x01\x08\x01\x01\x02\x02\x0a\x0a\x02\x0a\x02\x40')

print(bytes_sent)
```

I'm trying to use an array to fill this

```
bytes_sent = b'\x11\xb0\x12\x05\x0a\x0a\x0a\x01\x08\x01\x01\x02\x02\x0a\x0a\x02\x0a\x02\x40'
```

But don't works

```
bytes_sent = '(\x11\xb0\x12)' + (final_array[0]) + (final_array[1]) + (final_array[2]) + (final_array[3]) + '\x01\x08\x01\x01\x02\x02\x0a\x0a\x02\x0a\x02\x40')
```

Is there any way to send bytes in this format by importing values ​​from an array?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlKxt.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What are you trying to do? Perhaps I do not understand it because some of it is in Spanish, but this code is very confusing. Especially the second to last line with `bytes_enviados`.

Comment: What does the input look like? It would help to convert the code to English with clear inputs and current vs. desired output.  Don’t use images of text put it in the question as text.

Comment: is your goal to take a string with a 4 digit integer, e.g., `"1234"` and convert that to bytes? what is an example intput with corresponding output?

Comment: I just want to take this array hex_array = [05,0a,03,0a] to this: bytes_sent = b'\x05\x0a\x03\x0a  format, but with array values, sorry my bad english

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @dev-python `hex_array = [05,0a,03,0a]` is a *syntax error*. Are they strings? Your actual input seems to be a *single string*. There is no reason to be ambiguous here, You can tell us precisely. "hex" isn't a data type!

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear.
But it appears you're looking for the
[binascii](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) module.

```
>>> import binascii
>>> 
>>> bytes_sent = b'\x11\xb0\x12\x05\x0a\x0a\x0a\x01\x08\x01\x01\x02\x02\x0a\x0a\x02\x0a\x02\x40'
>>> 
>>> binascii.hexlify(bytes_sent)
b'11b012050a0a0a0108010102020a0a020a0240'
>>> 
>>> binascii.unhexlify('11b012050a0a0a0108010102020a0a020a0240')
b'\x11\xb0\x12\x05\n\n\n\x01\x08\x01\x01\x02\x02\n\n\x02\n\x02@'
```

If you additionally have some use case which
calls for mapping 0x00 to 0x0a, well, that's up to you.